# Properly Using Custom Converter in Json Model for a Dynamic JsonProperty Name

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, steam-web-api

I am working with some Json Data that has One Field for the AppID. Obviously this AppID changes based on what Application I'm querying. So searching online I found I could use a Custom Converter for this task, but my implementation seems to fail and I'm not sure why. Specifically it fails when attempting to print the data deserialized from the Json is returning null. My model (trimmed down) is as follows.

```
public partial class SteamAPIModel 
{
   [JsonProperty("AppIDJson")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(AppIDConverter))]
   public AppIDJson AppIDJson { get; set; }
}
public partial class AppIDJson
{
   [JsonProperty("success")]
   public bool success { get; set; }
   public Data data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Data
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string short_description { get; set; }
}

public class AppIDConverter : JsonConverter
{
   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
   {
      return objectType == typeof(AppIDJson);
   }
   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      //This int value here is declared in another class and accessed this way.
      return apiTask.ApplicationIDAPITask;
   }
   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
   }
```

For the model it all looks as far as I know standard except accessed the actual what I hope to be the property name from another class. Which that class is declared below, which I'll include my API call for clarity.

```
public class apiTask
{
   public static int ApplicationIDAPITask { get; set; }
   public static void Runner(int ApplicationIDSource)
   {
      ApplicationIDAPITask = ApplicationIDSource;
      RunAsync().Wait();
   }
   static async Task RunAsync()
   {
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/");
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         //in the below URL I do have a token in the final project to allow the number of queries needed for the project
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("&appids="+ ApplicationIDAPITask).ConfigureAwait(false);
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
            string httpResponseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            SteamAPIModel game_item = JsonConvert.DeserializedObject<SteamAPIModel>(httpResponseBody);
            if (game_item.AppIDJson != null)
            {
               Debug.WriteLine(game_item.AppIDJson.success.ToString());
            } else
            {
               //This is what executes currently, never completing the code in the if statement, 
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

While it may be a bit spaghetti code, the idea here is I could call apiTaks.Runner(App ID); with any valid AppID and then the API Request will be made with that AppID in it, which after it gets the results for that AppID it will be able to decode the Json properly with a Dynamic name. Because within the Raw Json the first field is the AppID int itself. And finally from there I hope to obviously be able to reference that data the same way the Print statement did within ApiTask.cs

Lastly to make sure I'm providing enough information part of the Json data returned is below...

```
{
   "730": {
      "success": true,
      "data": {
         "type": "game",
         "name": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
         "steam_appid": 730,
         "required_age": 0,
         "is_free": true,
         "controller_support": "full",
..........
```

Currently if I were to instead label "AppIDJson" as a specific AppID and make a query for that specific AppID everything does work as expected, so the rest of this code does work, I just wanted to include it for help troubleshooting where my issue is. Thank you for any help with this issue, and if theres anything else you notice in my code that can be improved, since nearly everything here is new to me on this project.

Comment: Do you actually need this converter? Newtonsoft JSON.net supports Dictionary deserialization: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm
You can deserialize `IDictionary<string, AppIDJson>` from the response, where `string Key` is AppID

Comment: I honestly wasn't sure I did, that was just a seeming solution I found at the time. But thank you and I will go ahead trying to use deserialization.